# Linux file Recovery

Tags: linux, file-recovery

Can anyone help me out in getting back a deleted file in linux.
Instead of giving this command " **rm -rvf *~** ", I gave " **rm -rvf *** ".

Is there any way to get all files back ??

Answer (score 2):

First think to do is power off the computer to avoid writing in the disk you delete your data.

After that, you can use one of several tools existing to recover. I like http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec, but it recover several file types an not only photos :)

You can also do an image of the disc you have deleted the files, and them, with your system up and running recover the files from the image (this works with photorec).

Some time ago I've similar problem and I find several tools to try recover the data. Each tools have some pros and cons. You can check this http://www.h-online.com/security/features/Digital-autopsy-747165.html and you will get an overview how data forensics works and in the last page you have listed some tools.

Comment: PhotoRec is the tool I recommend, so +1 to this.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully recovered deleted files from my ext3 partition using [ext3grep](http://code.google.com/p/ext3grep/).